# Install windows 7 on 15 inch macbook pro with a 13 inch MBP install disk

Tags: macbook-pro, windows

I have a 15 inch MBP which I want to install windows 7 on and I read online that I should have the MBP installation disk with me to install drivers and things after I install windows. I don't have it anymore.

My friend loaned me his 13 inch MBP install disk but it says clearly on the disk that it is for MBP 13 inches. I'm not sure if it will work, has anyone tried this before? Is it ok if I go ahead with the install?

Answer (score 2):

When you run the Boot Camp Assistant app it should offer to download the newest drivers for your MacBook Pro. You can just save them to a USB key and run the installer after you finish installing Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should work - Windows will install fine even without the disk, and the boot camp drivers are the same basic set.